# How to transform image via node.js for cloudinary

Tags: node.js, image-processing, cloudinary

I am unable to use the API of `Cloudinary` properly via `Node.js`. In their [documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#eager_transformations) it's as easy as this:

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload("sample.jpg", 
    { eager: [
        { width: 400, height: 300, crop: "pad" }, 
        { width: 260, height: 200, crop: "crop", gravity: "north"} ]}, 
    function(error, result) {console.log(result); });
```

Unfortunately no image with my `eager` settings is generated. Only my original image is uploaded. The amount of transformations does increase though even I'm not able to see an image with my settings under `Media Library`.

**Edit**:
When I call it via URL the image is delivered on the fly! Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using an eager transformation it creates the derived version of the image during the upload process rather than lazily or on the fly. Hence, the transformation is calculated on upload.
You can verify this by using the usage API-

`cloudinary.v2.api.usage(function(error, result){console.log(result)});`

You can find the URL that was generated in the response. So for example, your code will generate the following URL-

`http://res.cloudinary.com/<cloud_name>/image/upload/c_crop,g_north,h_200,w_260/v1518429787/sample.jpg`

Comment: Thank you @rcstraus for your answer. I was guessing that removing `v2` would also work ... unfortunately I stumpled over that (so it's working but not with eager!)!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for Cloudinary, not Cloudify. Please re-tag.

Comment: Thanks! That question is of course `cloudinary` related! :)

Answer (score 0):

What you did is correct. The response from cloudinary should be like below

```
  {
  asset_id: '7c40a8df3ac00dd62413f9dfb6425d8a',
  public_id: 'rrajl7nl6wxldmbsuouk',
  version: 1590261371,
  version_id: 'ecf752113f7d696e8fd79d1d4aad2176',
  signature: '8bc188c384580c669a77510ec9d93b9a60d45cd9',
  width: 4000,
  height: 6000,
  format: 'jpg',
  resource_type: 'image',
  created_at: '2020-05-23T19:16:11Z',
  tags: [ 'DSC_0884.JPG' ],
  bytes: 298518,
  type: 'upload',
  etag: 'e86babf3cb5cf25249753ac0b5ccca06',
  placeholder: false,
  url: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/pine-date/image/upload/v1590261371/rrajl7nl6wxldmbsuouk.jpg',
  secure_url: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/pine-date/image/upload/v1590261371/rrajl7nl6wxldmbsuouk.jpg',
  original_filename: 'tmp-2-1590261360679DSC_0884',
  original_extension: 'JPG',
  eager: [
    {
      transformation: 'c_fit,e_vibrance:80,h_300,w_400',
      width: 200,
      height: 300,
      bytes: 7325,
      format: 'jpg',
      url: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/pine-date/image/upload/c_fit,e_vibrance:80,h_300,w_400/v1590261371/rrajl7nl6wxldmbsuouk.jpg',
      secure_url: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/pine-date/image/upload/c_fit,e_vibrance:80,h_300,w_400/v1590261371/rrajl7nl6wxldmbsuouk.jpg'
    }
  ]
}
```

to get the eager transformed url you can access it from `result.eager[<transformationIndex>].url`